# chosen.js not update when options update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using `chosen.js` and now i faced with a problem, that when i want to append data dynamically with `ajax` it not update. according to **[official website](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html)** of chosen, you should use this:

```
$('.my_select_box').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

And i did, but it not working with ajax, but works with simple append. i put this code in success, but looks like this code runs faster than append. any idea?

```js
$('.chosen-select').chosen();

$('#Update').click(function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'xxxxx.json',
    success: function(data) {
      $('select').append('<option value="' + data[i]['id'] + '">' + data[i]['title'] + '</li>');
      $('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated'); // update chosen
    }
  });

});
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.css" />

<select class="chosen-select" multiple>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>

<a>Update</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use **[Select2](https://select2.org/)** because it support live append *(include ajax)* then you no need to use any `trigger` to change or update or anything elese. `Select2` is more `extensible` than `chosen`.

**[Dynamic item creation](https://select2.org/tagging)**

Easily convert `chosen` to `select2`:

```
$('.chosen-select').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select an option'
})
```

**Example:**

```js
$('.chosen-select').select2();
i = 3;
$('#Update').click(function() {
i++;
 $('select').append('<option>'+i+'</li>');

});
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" />

<select class="chosen-select" multiple>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>

<a id="Update">Update</a>
```